# Context vs Config classes

Tags: java

I am implementing some classes in my application and I am little bit confused on choosing **AppContext vs AppConfiguration**.

My application configs are in `YAML` files which are parsed in application startup. Currently we are planning `AppContext` for just simple properties and `AppConfiguration` for getting complex `properties/arrays`.

Comment: For me the difference between context and configuration is the "mutability". I don't expect the configuration to change during run but I expect the context to evolve.

Answer (score 1):

`ApplicationContext` is basically backbone of running Spring, while `configuration` is definition how to do that. So `context` must know how to instantiate a bean - that is why bean factory is mandatory. Also context can have parent context. There are some other things that context is responsible for - please read [the doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html).

`Configuration` can define context, or provide other static information used by the app to do what is needed. That information can be taken from many sources, can be refreshed, and so on - but still - that is more like parameter, input for `context`.